# ERROR in : IgxFormatSpecifier cannot be used as an entry component

Tags: angular, typescript

Please help me solve this , as I have no clue to solve this.Project has several modules, Code will be available on request.
This project works fine using **ng serve** but throw error on **ng build --prod**

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error was throwing at the time of publishing when use
ng build --prod
,I then switched to
ng build
Which was running without errors so it did publish all files with index.html